# WinUSB fails to install windows 7 on USB

Tags: grub2, usb, mount

I get a error saying:

```
Installation failed !
Exit code: 256
Log:
Formating device...
Mounting...
mount: block device /home/jeffrey/Desktop/Win7_sp1_32-64_EN-faXcooL.iso is     write-protected, mounting read-only
Copying...
Installing grub...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 421: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Error occured !
Syncing...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 12459 Terminated              while true; do
sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 12461 Terminated              while true; do
sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1437334971_3530'...
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1437334971_3530'...
```

I already formated my USB to ntfs.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that you try **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)** instead of WinUSB. **mkusb** can create bootable USB drives and memory cards with the Windows installer for Windows 7 - Windows 10.

See the following links,

### If you have a DVD drive

- Burn a boot DVD disk. Make sure to 'burn an iso file'. (Do *not* create a data DVD with the iso file.)

### Create a boot USB drive

- You can use mkusb-nox or mkusb-dus alias mkusb version 12. See these links,

  [Windows USB install drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation)

Answer (score 1):

**THERE IS A SIMPLER WAY.**

1. Run `sudo apt-get install gparted grub-pc-bin p7zip-full ntfs-3g` in terminal.
2. Format your USB Drive as NTFS and enable the bootable flag using GParted. To enable and Bootable flag, right-click the partition and choose `Manage flags` and then check `boot`. Format again if you see any error near partition name. Note down the partition name. It will be something like /dev/sdXY. X will be an alphabet and Y will be a number. e.g. /dev/sdb1
3. Download Unetbootin binary from https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html
4. Open Terminal and `cd <unetbootin_bin_directory>`. e.g `cd ~/Downloads`. Run `chmod +x unetbootin.bin` to make it executable.
5. Run `sudo ./unetbootin.bin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdXY` in terminal. **Make sure to replace X and Y with appropriate values.**
6. Select Windows 10 iso and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i make a bootable usb. Its not hard to do and u get the 
opportunity to play around with the terminal, but u do have to
be very careful not to format the wrong drives.
1. download what ever iso file u wanting to uses
2. download gparted if not installed 
3. open up leafpad or any other editor 
4. copy the following command and past it in leafpad so u can edit it

sudo dd bs=4M if=your.iso of=/dev/sdb

you will need to put the name of your iso file name and
you need to put the name of your drive "sbd" at the end

5. plug in the usb and open gparted and 
   format fat32 and get the name of the drive u will need
   to add it to your command line here sdb is put your drive name 
   and put the name of your.iso file 
   go head and put the iso file on desktop for now
6. type "cd Desktop"
   you need to be in the working directory where your.iso file is
7. now past the command with your.iso and drive name
   now this will not look like it doing anything but it copying all 
   the iso files to your usb after it done restart and test out your new bootable usb