# how to make windows bootable stick from iso.file in ubuntu 16.04 OS

Tags: 16.04, windows, live-usb

I want to make windows bootable stick from .iso file in ubuntu 16.04 OS, I have tried many thinks suggested in community but none seems to work for me, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't tell us you tried many things, tell us exactly what things you tried. We can't read your mind and neither of us profits from wasting time by suggesting the same over and over again. So, what exactly did you tried and at which point did these methods fail?

Comment: You can try mkusb-dus or mkusb-nox, which can create Windows install drives for Windows 7 - 10. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/650333/winusb-fails-to-install-windows-7-on-usb/924309#924309