# Unable to create bootable usb in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, live-usb

I'm trying to convert a Windows 7 iso file to bootable usb through Startup disk creator.

Startup disk creator not detecting my Windows 7 iso file.

But it detacts my Ubuntu iso file.

Note: It not detecting any windows iso's. But it detects all Ubuntu iso's.

Any restrictions with iso file name..?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the name of the "Windows 7 ISO"? Where is it located, compared to your "Ubuntu ISO" file? What's the ownership and permissions of each?

Comment: You can use mkusb to create a USB install drive for Windows. See these links, https://askubuntu.com/questions/650333/winusb-fails-to-install-windows-7-on-usb/924309#924309 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you should use a program that allows you to boot iso of windows, surely the program that you use only allows to do it with iso gnu / linux, if this is not the problem should be iso problem.

I leave you a link that can help you.

[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)