# Computer won't boot from Windows USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

I currently am on Ubuntu 17.10 and I am trying to install Windows. (Later I will dual boot with ubuntu 16.04 LTS (it's more stable)). I have burnt the Windows iso to a USB but my computer will not boot from it. The boot order is correct.

Is this because I have Ubuntu or GRUB installed? How do I do this? I have an Ubuntu live CD if that helps.

Comment: How did you try to create the Windows installer drive? Maybe you can try according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/650333/winusb-fails-to-install-windows-7-on-usb/924309#924309

Comment: The answer was found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/650333/winusb-fails-to-install-windows-7-on-usb/924309#924309